# Idea Intellij include non-menu actions by default

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to ensure the `Include non-menu actions` checkbox in the Run actions window is always turned on by default?

I'm quite tired of having to press <kbd>Сtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> twice to run a maven build (a non-menu action)!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is not. Your best best would be to record a simple macro (Edit > Macros) and record the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> twice. Give it a name and then map a different shortcut to it in *Settings > Keymap*

If you wanted to move the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> mapping to the macro, In theory you should be to record the "Action:FindMacro" step followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to select the checkbox using its *n* accelerator. However a bug surfaced when I did that. When the macro runs, the "Open Tasks" dialog opens which is mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. It appears that the when the macro interpreter sees the uppercase N, it adds a shift key to the playback. I went in and manually edited the 'N' to 'n' and that resolved the issue. (I reported the bug via [IDEA-124492](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124492)).

After working through that, another issue surfaced. The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> sequence was getting sent too quickly. So I needed a pause between the ''Open Find Action Dialog''. Since I am unaware of a way to add a pause in a recorded macro (I opened feature request [IDEA-124493](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124493) to allow such) I instead inserted a few <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> sequences as a hacked pause. Since the default behavior when opening the *Find Actions* dialog is for the previous search string to be selected, this does not end up changing any behavior.

If you want to use this macro, close IntelliJ IDEA. Open the file `config/options/macro.xml`. (See this [document](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) to learn where the IntelliJ IDEA `config` directory is.) If the file is not present, create one with the structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
  <component name="ActionMacroManager">
  </component>
</application>
```

Then in the `<component>` element, insert the macro:

```
<macro name="Find non-menu Action">
  <action id="GotoAction" />
  <shortuct text="control a" />
  <shortuct text="control a" />
  <shortuct text="control a" />
  <shortuct text="control a" />
  <shortuct text="alt n" />
</macro>
```

Save and restart IntelliJ IDEA. You can then remap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> mapping to it via *Settings > [IDE Settings] > Keymap > Macros*.

I found on my system I needed four of the "pauses" via the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> commands. Three was intermittently successful. So it was right on the edge of the pause needed. You may need to increase those.

Just as a side note in case it helps you, you can assign a shortcut to a maven goal.

Comment: This does work, however multiple pressing of Ctrl + Shift+ a messes this up.

Also - the file should be named **macros.xml** not macro.xml.

I know I can set my own shortcut to a maven goal, but this was just an example. I would like to use it for other things as well, and having seperate shortcuts for all the actions would be impossible.

Anyway @MarkVedder thanks for your help!

Comment: This solution is not usable. It initially works, however it stopped working after a while. It works only the first time, then it acts as though  Ctrl + Shift+ a was pressed multiple times, which screwes up how finding actions works.